# How to use useEffect deps when page reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I got simple blog with arficles, and when user click edit button he got form filled with articles data - title,  description, body and tags. I use useEffect to get data and fill form, when I got "id". If there is no "id" form should be blank. here is my useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      isLoading = true;
      return props.onLoad(userService.articles.get(id));
    }
    props.onLoad(null);
    }, [id]
  );
```

but when I reload page id not changed, and func userService.articles.get(id) not run, and all datas gone. I need advice how to fix it? may be I need to use other deps for useEffect, but now I have no idea what deps i can use exept id.

upd:
thank you all for help. all i want is:

1. when the edit page load/reload and "id" exist -> fills form fields
2. when "id" not exist -> blank form fields

now when I reload edit page i got id - but all datas gone, and i got blank form :(

Here is the full code: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-silence-9prc4?file=/src/components/Articles/ArticleEditor.js)

p.s. i use free API - so you can create user in a sec with any imagined email, username and password. you don't need mail confirmation.

Comment: I think you might need to `console.log(id)` to see if there is any changes: > but when I reload page id not changed, and func userService.articles.get(id) not run

Comment: What does props.onLoad expects to receive as an argument, an `array` maybe?

Comment: @NemanjaLazarevic, props.onLoad works fine and i got all needed data in console. but form fields is blank when page reloaded.

Comment: You should post more code, we don't know where `id` is coming from.
Is it an expected behaviour to see an empty form when there is no `id` to fetch the `articles`?

Comment: ty, post updated, added link to full code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this.props.match.params` to access your `id` that comes from the url.

```
    useEffect(() => {
      if (props.match.params.id) {
        setIsloading(true);
        userService.articles.get(props.match.params.id)
          .then((resp) => {
            setIsloading(false);
            props.onLoad(resp)
         })
    } else {
      props.onLoad(null);
    }
  }, [props.match.params.id]);
```

Also you should rely on `useState` to manage your `isLoading` variable.

```
 const [isLoading, setIsloading] = useState(false);
```

I did a bit more digging into the code you have provided.
The `initialValues` will be first empty because the data coming from the `props` is not there yet. And once the `initialValues` have been set you can't change them dynamically, you have to resort to the antd `Form` api.

> You cannot set value for each form control via value or `defaultValue`
> prop, you should set default value with `initialValues` of Form. Note that `initialValues` cannot be updated by `setState` dynamically, you
> should use `setFieldsValue` in that situation.

The key here is to use another `useEffect` with dependencies to your form values comming from the `props` and use those to reset the form values via `setFieldsValue`.

Comment: tnx a lot. but is an error "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" when press edit button.

Comment: Probably `props` was missing from the dependencies list. I've updated the answer.
I couldn't access the Edit page because I couldn't login. Give it a try with the updated answer.

Comment: If `onLoad` doesn't return the `promise` you might also experience the error you mentioned.

Comment: ty again, its free API - you can create user in a sec with any imagined email, username and password.

Answer (score 0):

try to useEffect without options and it will run just when the page loads for the first time

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      isLoading = true;
      return props.onLoad(userService.articles.get(id));
    }
    props.onLoad(null);
    }, []
  );
```

Comment: hmm, i think i missunderstood this react hook :( when i remove id from deps my form is always blank. but with id as deps it fills form when the page loaded first time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption that you want props.onLoad to run whenever there is a defined "id" or the defined "id" changes:

Returning a function from a useEffect hook (as you do with return props.onLoad(...)) is specifically for "cleaning up" things like side effects or subscriptions. A function returned inside a useEffect hook will only run when the component **unmounts**. See docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1). Also it doesn't seem like you are even passing a function to run on cleanup. You're passing the result of props.onLoad to run on cleanup, which based on the function name doesn't seem like it is intended to return another function.

So, if you want props.onLoad() to run if the "id" is defined, remove the return before props.onLoad. That return is telling React to hold (what it thinks is a function) for cleanup on unmount. If it's still not working, I think we'll need more information on what exactly props.onLoad is doing.

Comment: ty. I upd post and I added link to my code. Its first time when I try to use hooks.. I wrote this code with classes. but still can't convert it to functional components and hooks :(